# gearman jobs after running for some time, request will timeout

Tags: gearman

Use a gearman server, registered a function 'stop_xxxxx', then do fatigue testing (cycle request 1000000 times). 
At first, the response speed is normal, but by about 1000 times Request timed out.

I'm using gearman 1.1.12 and gearman-python

When timeouts are, gearman server logs are: 

`DEBUG 2014-07-09 02:26:34.899149 [proc] Received submission, function: A_stop_xxxxxxxx unique: 98588d0149f0a2deb32919e36e395a8a with 2 arguments -> libgearman-server/server.cc: 248 
   DEBUG 2014-07-09 02:26:34.899166 [proc] Comparing queue 1 to limit 0 for priority 1 -> libgearman-server/job.cc: 175 
   DEBUG 2014-07-09 02:26:34.899281 [proc] JOB H: orainxiong-vm: 1734: 2878034076 -> libgearman-server/job.cc: 240 
   DEBUG 2014-07-09 02:26:34.899542 [12] Received RUN wakeup event -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc: 624 
  NOTICE 2014-07-09 02:26:34.899573 [proc] accepted, A_stop_one_perf_collect, 98588d0149f0a2deb32919e36e395a8a, 0 -> libgearman-server/server.cc: 317 
   DEBUG 2014-07-09 02:26:34.899631 [12] send () 32 bytes to peer -> libgearman-server/io.cc: 403 
   DEBUG 2014-07-09 02:26:34.899646 [12] Sent JOB_CREATED -> libgearman-server/thread.cc: 356 
   **no more output**`

Did not seem to send the request to the worker, how to locate the problem?

My boot parameters are:

> > gearmand - job-retries = 3 - worker-wakeup = 1 - round-robin - verbose DEBUG - queue-type = MySQL - mysql-host = 127.0.0.1 - mysql-port = 3306 - mysql -user = xxx - mysql-password = xxx - mysql-db = xxxx - mysql-table = job_queue-p 4371-t 16-lstderr